# Parity of shuffle permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

A $(p,q)$-shuffle is a permutation $\sigma$ of the set $\{1, \dots, p, p+1, \dots,p+q\}$ such that $$\sigma(1)<\dots<\sigma(p)$$ and $$\sigma(p+1) < \dots<\sigma(p+q)\,.$$

It is known that the [number of $(p,q)$-shuffles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riffle_shuffle_permutation) is ${p+q \choose p}$.

Looking at the case $p+q = 6$ and considering the parity of shuffles, I was surprised to find that

- $3$ of the ${6 \choose 1} = 6$ $(1,5)$-shuffles have even parity
- $9$ of the ${6 \choose 2} = 15$ $(2,4)$-shuffles have even parity
- $10$ of the ${6 \choose 3} = 20$ $(3,3)$-shuffles have even parity
- $9$ of the ${6 \choose 4} = 15$ $(4,2)$-shuffles have even parity
- $3$ of the ${6 \choose 5} = 6$ $(5,1)$-shuffles have even parity

It's not so difficult to believe that the number of even $(p,q)$-shuffles should equal the number of even $(q,p)$-shuffles. But I was very surprised to see that there are so many more even than odd $(2,4)$-shuffles.

Are any closed-form solutions known for the number of even $(p,q)$-shuffles? If not, is anything known about the asymptotic behaviour?

Comment: I have no time to give a full answer, but the generating polynomial of (p,q)-shuffles according to length is a Gaussian coefficient. So you can deduce the answer you're looking for by evaluating it at -1, which counts even permutations minus odd permutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Philippe suggests in the comments, it is well know that 
$$\sum_{\sigma \text{ is a $(a,b)$-shuffle}} q^{\ell(\sigma)}={a+b \choose b}_q$$
where the $q$-binomial coefficient (or Gaussian binomial coefficient) on the right side is defined by 
$${n \choose k}_q=\frac{[n]_q! }{[k]_q! [n-k]_q!}$$
where $[n]_q!=[1]_q [2]_q \cdots [n]_q$ and $[n]_q=1+q+\cdots +q^{n-1}$.

Thus the difference between the number of even and odd shuffles is obtained by specializing at $q=-1$.  This polynomial is palindromic, so, depending on the parity, one either gets 0 or the middle (and largest) coefficient of the polynomial ${a+b \choose b}_q$.

Precise asymptotics for this coefficient (and others) are given in Theorem 1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08375.pdf) by Melczer, Panova, and Pemantle.

Comment: "q = -1"/"cyclic sieving" should tell you that this counts the number of binary words with a 0s and b 1s that are palindromic.

Comment: (Not to hard to prove that with a sign-reversing involution, in fact.)

Comment: More generally there's a simple formula for a $q$-binomial coefficient evaluated at a root of unity, sometimes called the $q$-Lucas theorem, due, as far as I know, to Gloria Olive (Generalized powers. Amer. Math. Monthly 72 (1965), 619–627) and often rediscovered. See, e.g., https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313551/a-divisibility-of-q-binomial-coefficients-combinatorially/313557#313557